# How to convert Google document to MS Word format using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I created a Google document file in Google Drive. How can I convert that file to a Word document using Google Drive API.

Answer (score 2):

## Drive v3

> Depending on the type of download you'd like to perform — a file, a Google Document, or a content link — you'll use one of the following URLs:
>
> - Download a file — [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) with `alt=media` [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)
> - Download and export a Google Doc — [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)
> - Link a user to a file — `webContentLink` from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

---

## Drive v2

> Depending on the type of download you'd like to perform — a file, a Google Document, or a content link — you'll use one of the following URLs:
>
> - Download a file — either [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) with `alt=media`, or `downloadURL` from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource)
> - Download and export a Google Doc — `exportLinks` from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource)
> - Link a user to a file — `webContentLink` from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource)

Google Doc formats and supported export MIME types map to each other as follows:

```
MS Word document application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

If you are trying to do it programmatically try following this [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20009-convert-google-documents) using Apps Script.